# Entropy and Reversible Specific Heat

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I'm confused about the usage of the entropy equation in thermodynamics. Specifically, how it is used for irreversible and reversible processes. Entropy is defined to be the following:
$$\Delta S = \int \frac{dq_{rev}}{T}$$

So I was following this guide to calculate the change in entropy for an irreversible process: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/#comments.

However, I'm confused regarding this part where the author calculates the change in entropy for 2 objects attaining thermal equilibrium:

"Starting from State 1, we first separate the two objects.  We then take Object 1 and contact it with a continuous sequence of constant temperature reservoirs, running (very gradually) from its initial temperature TH to its final temperature (Th+TC)/2.  Similarly, for Object 2, we contact it with a continuous sequence of constant temperature reservoirs, running (very gradually) from its initial temperature TC to its final temperature (Th+TC)/2. Step 4:  For the selected reversible path, evaluate the integral of dq/T from the initial state to the final state.  This will be the change of entropy."

The author then shows that:
$$\Delta S = \int \frac{dq_{rev}}{T} = \int mCdT/T = mCln(T_f/Ti)$$

So the author identifies the reversible path but still proceeds to use the irreversible heat to find the change in entropy. Isn't the specific heat equation, which is used in this case for a spontaneous heat transfer process, irreversible?

So why is it that we can use things like:

$$\Delta S_{phase} = \frac{mL}{T}$$

$$\Delta S_{specific-heat} = mCln(\frac{T_f}{T_i})$$

To find entropy change when all those heats that are used to find the entropy equation are clearly irreversible?

Comment: Sorry not really. I understand the whole idea of entropy and reversible paths. What I don't understand is how specific heat is reversible heat that we can use to find the change in entropy.

Comment: Use of the heat capacity is not restricted to either reversible or irreversible processes. Chet describes a reversible process and then applies the heat capacity. Therefore, I don't understand your comment "proceeds to use the irreversible heat."

Comment: So what exactly changes when we use mCdT for an irreversible process vs a reversible process? Don't they yield the same value? Wouldnt that mean we indirectly used the actual heat to calculate the entropy and not the reversible heat?

Comment: Ok so now Im looking at Chet's other reply here:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/596146/if-t-ds-dq-only-for-reversible-processes-why-can-i-use-it-for-non-reversibl?rq=1

So is it the deltaT that is coming into play here?

Comment: For this example, the heat to raise the object's temperature reversibly is the same as the heat to raise the object's temperature in that particular irreversible scenario.

Comment: It isn't the heat that is different for an irreversible path, it's the temperaturethat that is used in the denominator that's different.  The Clausius inequality calls for the use of the temperature at the boundary when integrating, not the average temperature of the body.  This is the temperature through which dq flows into the system..  During the irreversible path, the boundary temperature through which dq flows is $(T_H+T_C)/2$, not the temperature of the sequence of reservoirs T for the reversible path.

Comment: Got it! So for the irr path, the temp we use is the average temp? If so when you calculate the entropy using the reversible path why do we still use (Th+Tc)/2? What changes really?

Comment: Or is it that the boundaries for the irr and rev paths are different when we separate them?